# Shell and system functions in R returns an error that doesn't appear in windows cmd

Tags: r, windows, shell, cmd

I am on windows 7 nad use latest version of R.

If I run following commands in cmd:

```
@FOR /f \"tokens=*\" %i IN ('docker-machine env default') DO @%i
docker run hello-world
```

everything works as expected. But if I run the same inside R using `shell` or `system` functions:

```
shell("@FOR /f \"tokens=*\" %i IN ('docker-machine env default') DO @%i", intern = TRUE)
shell("docker run hello-world")
```

it returns an error:

```
docker: error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.31/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
See 'docker run --help'.
Warning message:
In shell("docker run hello-world") :
  'docker run hello-world' execution failed with error code 127
```

(same for system function).

Why does the same command work in cmd and doesn't work in R?

EDIT:

Error with full path:

```
> shell('"C:/Program Files/Docker Toolbox/docker.exe" run hello-world')
C:/Program Files/Docker Toolbox/docker.exe: error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.31/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
See 'C:/Program Files/Docker Toolbox/docker.exe run --help'.
Warning message:
In shell("\"C:/Program Files/Docker Toolbox/docker.exe\" run hello-world") :
  '"C:/Program Files/Docker Toolbox/docker.exe" run hello-world' execution failed with error code 127
```

Comment: `net helpmsg 127` returns *The specified procedure could not be found.*. This is what one expects from programmers that act like programming is typing. It's not. Use full paths.

Comment: Full paths doesn't help.

Comment: If using a fully-qualified path does not help, does it produce the same error message? If not, please include the error message text in the question.